# Error in Eclipse: "java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation"

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting this error message in eclipse `java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem`. This is the code.

```
public class AreaOfSquare {
public static void main (String [] args){ }
    int base;
    int height;
    int area;

    base = 10;
    height = 10;
    area = base * height;

 }
```

The error seems to be around declaring the last variable but i don't know what the problem is...

Comment: Are you using eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem"

This means that you're trying to run code that won't compile, something that you should never do. Instead, you should compile first and fix all compilation errors ***before*** trying to run your code.

As for your specific problem, your curly braces don't go around your main method body, and your class is missing a closing brace. You have code dangling out where it doesn't belong, neither in a method, nor constructor, nor initializer block.

So change this:

```
public class AreaOfSquare {
    public static void main (String [] args){ }
        int base;
        int height;
        int area;

        base = 10;
        height = 10;
        area = base * height;
    }
```

to this:

```
public class AreaOfSquare {
    public static void main (String [] args){ 
        int base;
        int height;
        int area;

        base = 10;
        height = 10;
        area = base * height;

        System.out.println("area is: " + area);
    }
}
```

You will want to study the first few chapters of any good Java textbook which will show you how to construct simple Java classes that compile and work.